# system() 's not behaving like cmd in R under windows

Tags: r, windows, system, gdal, rgdal

In R, I execute the command

```
> system('"C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdalwarp.exe" -tap  -overwrite  -tr 100 100
 -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs" -r "bilinear" -of "GTiff" "D:/Maps/EMODnet/output/tmp/tmp.tif"
 "D:/Maps/EMODnet/output/tmp/tmp_proj.tif"')
```

and got the error

> ERROR 1: PROJ:
> proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate
> operations from `GEOGCRS["unknown",DATU

but when I execute directly in a windows "cmd" terminal the following it is successful

> "C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdalwarp.exe" -tap  -overwrite  -tr 100 100 -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs" -r "bilinear" -of "GTiff" "D:/Maps/EMODnet/output/tmp/tmp.tif" "D:/Maps/EMODnet/output/tmp/tmp_proj.tif"

Any idea why I get get that kind of difference ?

Comment: I don't have a Windows PC anymore but my hunch would be that the permissions and possible the user is different via `system()`. Maybe try `whoami` in cmd and R?

Comment: You may want to switch to `shell`. Edit: More extensive tutorial + description: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/01/working-with-windows-cmd-system-commands-in-r/

Comment: @JBGruber whoami is not recognized in cmd, I used echo %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% and they give both sophia\robin.girard